# How to define new division class after lightbox gallery and create footer?

Tags: html, css, lightbox

I have given header, a menu bar and a hero image, after that created image gallery using lightbox. I have create 4 columns with 3 images each, but in the lightbox gallery it's showing 3 columns with 4 images each.

I have given new row called My Videos but the css taking the previous row into consideration not the new one. I placed a video but it's not moving according to the margins given.

Lastly, my footer is not showing up..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Project One </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/lightbox.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div class="header-section">
            <div class="header-logo">
               <h1> Superstar </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="header-right">
               <p> Plot No.33,Mahalaxmi Nagar, Vizianagaram-535 002.<br>
                  email:saisankarmandala@gmail.com. 
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <div class="hero-text">
         <h1> I am Creative </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <h1> My Gallery </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-8-pushdown-sm">
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb1.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb1a.jpg" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb2.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb2a.jpg" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb3.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb3a.jpg" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb4.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb4a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb5.png" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb5a.png" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb6.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb6a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb7.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb7a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb8a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb9a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb10.jpeg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb10a.jpeg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb11.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb11a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb12.png" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb12a.png" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="heading">
            <h1> My Videos </h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
         <div class="video-area">
            <video height="150" width="200" controls>
               <source src="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/vids/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
               <source src="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/vids/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <footer>
         <p>&copy 2021, All rights reserved </p>
      </footer>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

This is my CSS Code

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}


/*styling the header section */

.header-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
  background-color: purple;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}


/* divide the header area into two and make width adjustments */

.header-logo {
  width: 66%;
  float: left;
  flex: 1;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.header-right {
  width: 34%;
  float: right;
  flex: 1;
}

p {
  font-size: 110%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 40px 0px 0px 150px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  margin-top: -5px;
}

nav {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 0px;
  bottom-border: none;
  border-top: 0px solid purple;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  width: 100%;
  height: 42px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a {
  display: inline;
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-bottom: 1px;
  border-spacing: 3px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-top: -2px;
}


/* hero image area */

.container {
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-top: 45px;
  background-image: url('C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/nude.jpg');
  height: 75%;
  position: relative;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: right center;
}


/* hero text on the image */

.hero-text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
  color: purple;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  width: 80%;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* row heading */

.row h1 {
  margin-top: -10px;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: purple;
}


/* image gallery settings */

.column {
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
  column-gap: 20px;
}

.thumbnails img {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 20px 10px 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  transitiion: all 2s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.thumbnails img:hover {
  transform: rotate(2deg);
  box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1)rotate(2deg);
  .thumbnails:hover img {
    opacity: .5;
    transform: scale(.92);
  }
  .row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: table;
  }
  .heading h1 {
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: purple;
  }
  .video-area video {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
  .footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
  }
```

Comment: I haven't checked if this is the cause of the problem, but you either have posted incomplete CSS, or a closing bracket is missing for `.thumbnails img:hover { ...`

Answer (score 0):

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  body {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
  }
  
  
  /*styling the header section */
  
  .header-section {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border-bottom: 2px solid purple;
    background-color: purple;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    overflow: auto;
  }
  
  
  /* divide the header area into two and make width adjustments */
  
  .header-logo {
    width: 66%;
    float: left;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  h1 {
    font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 300%;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .header-right {
    width: 34%;
    float: right;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  p {
    font-size: 110%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 40px 0px 0px 150px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  nav li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    margin-top: -5px;
  }
  
  nav {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 0px;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-top: 0px solid purple;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: purple;
    width: 100%;
    height: 42px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  
  nav a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  nav a {
    display: inline;
    font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px;
    border-spacing: 3px;
    background-color: purple;
    color: white;
    margin-right: 2px;
    margin-top: -2px;
  }
  
  
  /* hero image area */
  
  .container {
    max-width: 100%;
    margin-top: 45px;
    background-image: url('C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/nude.jpg');
    height: 75%;
    position: relative;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: right center;
  }
  
  
  /* hero text on the image */
  
  .hero-text {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    /* Black w/opacity/see-through */
    color: purple;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 3px solid #f1f1f1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 30px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  
  /* row heading */
  
  .row h1 {
    margin-top: -10px;
    font-size: 150%;
    font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: purple;
  }
  
  
  /* image gallery settings */
  
  .column {
    display: flex;
    align-items: stretch;
    column-gap: 20px;
  }
  
  .thumbnails img {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 30px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    transition:all 2s ease-in-out;
    
    border: 1px solid grey;
    box-sizing: border-box
  }
  
  .thumbnails img:hover {
    transform: rotate(2deg);
    box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1)rotate(2deg);
  }
    .thumbnails:hover img {
      opacity: .5;
      transform: scale(.92);
    }
    .row::after {
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;
    }
    .heading h1 {
      font-size: 150%;
      font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      color: purple;
    }
    .video-area video {
      margin: 0 auto;
      display: block;
    }
    .footer {
      position: fixed;
      width: 100%;
      bottom: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title> Project One </title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/main.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/lightbox.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
    </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div class="header-section">
            <div class="header-logo">
               <h1> Superstar </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="header-right">
               <p> Plot No.33,Mahalaxmi Nagar, Vizianagaram-535 002.<br>
                  email:saisankarmandala@gmail.com. 
               </p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </header>
      <nav>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/htmls/index.html">Contact Us</a></li>
         </ul>
      </nav>
      <div class="container"></div>
      <div class="hero-text">
         <h1> I am Creative </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <h1> My Gallery </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="col col-md-8-pushdown-sm">
         
         <div class="column">
          <div class="thumbnails">
             <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb4.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
             <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb4a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
             <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb5.png" data-lightbox="gallery">
             <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb5a.png" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
             <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb6.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
             <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb6a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
          </div>
       </div>
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb4.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb4a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb5.png" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb5a.png" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb6.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb6a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb7.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb7a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb8.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb8a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb9.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb9a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="column">
            <div class="thumbnails">
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb10.jpeg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb10a.jpeg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb11.jpg" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb11a.jpg" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
               <a href="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb12.png" data-lightbox="gallery">
               <img src="c:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/thumb12a.png" alt="thumb" width="200" height="200"></a>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
         <div class="heading">
            <h1> My Videos </h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
         <div class="video-area">
            <video height="150" width="200" controls>
               <source src="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/vids/vid1.mp4" type="video/mp4" >
               <source src="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/vids/vid2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            </video>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
      <footer>
         <p>&copy 2021, All rights reserved </p>
      </footer>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="C:/Users/saisa/OneDrive/Desktop/HTML TUTORIAL/p1/lightbox-plus-jquery.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```